# unity Add selected card in a canvas panel to a dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got displayed cards in a scene, they are gameobjects with this script:

```
public class CardClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    DeckBuildManager deckManager;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        deckManager = FindObjectOfType<DeckBuildManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    public void AddToDeck()
    {
        if (deckManager.DeckCards.Count <= 9)
        {
            if (!deckManager.DeckCards.ContainsValue(this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard.cardName))
            {
                deckManager.DeckCards.Add(this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard, this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard.cardName);
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Cards got a button component which use the AddToDeck function when clicked but there are impossible to click.
What can i do to click them?
I use panel to display those cards so its impossible to delete the panel in case it was the error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/taGixkk

Comment: What is the dictionary that holds these cards? In the screenshot you posted, it looks like the field `DataCard` is empty. Are you sure both if conditionals are being passed? What is the current count of the `DeckCards`? Is it below 9?  Are you sure you want to look for the `ContainsValue` or do you want to use `ContainsKey`?

Comment: @TEEBQNE I load all on play, the datas are ok, i can make another screenshot when game is on play.

Comment: @TEEBQNE i read the card values from a database

Comment: I do not see any direct issue with how your hierarchy is set up. The way that UI elements work is the further down in the hierarchy, the further up it is rendered so clicks will hit whatever the lowest element is. Meaning if there is any sort of UI that covers your screen that is under your cards, then the click is being eaten by them. I can write an answer to help debug to see if that is the case.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I used eventsystems with pointClick to add them.

Answer (score 0):

[resolv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoch1.jpg)

```
public void ClickOnCard()
{
    if (deckManager.DeckCards.Count <= 9)
    {
        if (!deckManager.DeckCards.ContainsValue(this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard.cardName))
        {
            deckManager.DeckCards.Add(this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard, this.gameObject.GetComponent<CardValues>().dataCard.cardName);
        }
    }
}
```